# Check if one of many temporary table exists and have values in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

i have a stored procedure where i insert results of many controls in temporary table, at the end i have to check if all table exists and if are empty or not

i start with

```
    IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo1) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo2) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo3) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo4) 
        ...
```

but i get error when some table does not exists so i have to mix those chek with

```
OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblControllo1') IS NOT NULL
```

but i don't find an elegant way to do it other than

```
DECLARE @controllo BIT = 1

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblControllo1') IS NOT NULL
        IF(EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo1) )
            SET @controllo = 0

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblControllo2') IS NOT NULL
        IF(EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo2) )
            SET @controllo = 0

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblControllo3') IS NOT NULL
        IF(EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo3) )
            SET @controllo = 0

    ....

IF(@controllo = 1)
-- do stuff
```

is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'd say there may be a bit different approaches but none that are with better performance. I'd just say change your individual check logic to `IF OBJECT_ID(...) IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (...) SET @controllo = 0`.

Comment: What will your proc be doing in the event that a table is either empty or undefined?

Comment: if all tables are empty or does not exists the system send an email saying it's all ok

Comment: i edited a little the post with correct check

Comment: Would you be expecting to find anything though... Temporary tables only exist for the session you're using. For example, open a session in SSMS and run the SQL `CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int);`. Now open a new query window (don't close your existing one), and run `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1;`. notice it doesn't return anything. So, in all honestly, I'd be expect this SP to also say the Temporary tables don't exist.

Comment: this is clear all code is inside a stored procedure and execute in a sungle run. to tell all the story: i test an anomanly saving result in temp table, if found something i send mail with this result; i repeat this for many controls. at the end i want to test if all test was successful and i do it looking to all temporary table

Comment: `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblControllo1') IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #tblControllo1)` returns error when temp table does not exists

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that you can't execute directly an SQL with `SELECT` of a table that may not exist because it will throw an error when trying to execute it. The following script uses a Dynamic SQL with a cursor to validate each table you need, breaking at the first failed condition.

```
DECLARE @AtLeastOneValidationFails BIT = 0

DECLARE TemporaryTableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        G.TemporaryTableName
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ('#FirstTable'), -- Your tables to validate here
            ('#SecondTable')) 
        AS G (TemporaryTableName)

DECLARE @TemporaryTableName VARCHAR(100)

OPEN TemporaryTableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TemporaryTableCursor INTO @TemporaryTableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + @TemporaryTableName) IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @AtLeastOneValidationFails = 1
        BREAK
    END

    DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TemporaryTableName + ')
            SET @ExistFails = 1'

    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @stmt = @DynamicSQL,
        @params = N'@ExistFails BIT OUTPUT',
        @ExistFails = @AtLeastOneValidationFails OUTPUT

    IF @AtLeastOneValidationFails = 1
        BREAK

    FETCH NEXT FROM TemporaryTableCursor INTO @TemporaryTableName

END

CLOSE TemporaryTableCursor
DEALLOCATE TemporaryTableCursor


SELECT
    AtLeastOneValidationFails = @AtLeastOneValidationFails
```

This will ensure that the tables exists before issuing the `SELECT` (thus not failing). Please be careful with table names as this is executing Dynamic SQL.

You can wrap this in a procedure and pass the table names as parameter so you don't repeat it everywhere. You can also edit it to return the failed table name so you can debug it properly.

PD: You can omit the `TOP N` when doing an `EXISTS` as the engine is smart enough to just check if the resulting query has at least 1 row.